# Convert list of nested dictionaries to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data that is converted to a list. How do I convert this to a `DataFrame` such that each row in that list becomes a column in the `DataFrame`?

```
[{'date': '2019-01-01',
  'stats': [{'metrics': {'comp_1': 149, 
                         'comp_2': 276}}]},
 {'date': '2019-01-02',
  'stats': [{'metrics': {'comp_1': 232, 
                         'comp_2': 842}}]}]
```

I tried to do `pd.DataFrame(c)` where `c` was the variable holding the list but I saw all components of each date was stored in a single row

Expected output:

```
date, comp_1, comp_2
2019-01-01,149,276
2019-01-02,232,842
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`json.json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) first:

```
a = [{'date': '2019-01-01',
'stats': [{'metrics': {'comp_1': 149,
 'comp_2': 276}}]},
{'date': '2019-01-02',
'stats': [{'metrics': {'comp_1': 232,
 'comp_2': 842}}]}]

from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

df = json_normalize(a,'stats', ['date'])
print (df)
   metrics.comp_1  metrics.comp_2        date
0             149             276  2019-01-01
1             232             842  2019-01-02
```

Last convert columns names to list and reorder by subset:

```
df = df[df.columns[-1:].tolist() + df.columns[:-1].tolist()]
print (df)
         date  metrics.comp_1  metrics.comp_2
0  2019-01-01             149             276
1  2019-01-02             232             842
```

EDIT:

Solution with loop:

```
out = []
for x in a:
    for k, v in x.items():
        for z in v:
            if isinstance(z, dict):
                d = z['metrics']
                d['year'] = x['date']
                out.append(d)

df = pd.DataFrame(out)   
print (df)
   comp_1  comp_2        year
0     149     276  2019-01-01
1     232     842  2019-01-02
```

Comment: the output I see has a date column and another column that stores both the metrics as a dict.. thanks..

Comment: @scottmartin - so input values `a` are different?

Comment: the only difference at my end is I have changed the metric label .. Everything else is same.

Comment: @scottmartin - are daat in json file? Maybe need `with open('file.json') as data_file:    
    df = json.load(data_file)`

Comment: I load this data from another system so I have done this to get the list mentioned above.. `b = json.loads(a.decode('utf-8'))` and then I perform `c = list(b)` and I tried doing the steps you mentioned to the variable `c`

Comment: @scottmartin - one question - it working for you with sample data like in answer? And not working with real data?

Comment: same for both the data sets

Comment: @scottmartin - What is your pandas version? Tested in pandas 0.25.0

Comment: using version 0.23.0

Comment: @scottmartin - so there is problem, is possible upgrade?

Comment: thank you this worked in the new version (0.25.0). However any advice on how to make it work on older version like 0.23.0